# What do I need after an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an INSERT statement, followed by a SQLITE3_EXEC, followed by a SELECT statement and another SQLITE3_EXEC.  I'm getting an SQLERROR 21 (SQLITE_MISUSE) on the EXEC for the SELECT statement.

Am I missing something between the two EXECs?  like a COMMIT, or?

Is it possible that the 21 refers to trying to insert a record that already exists?

```
    NSString *insertCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CardData (CARD_ID, CARD_NAME, CODE_VAL) VALUES ('/%@', '/%@', '/%@')",
                               symbol.data, @"Test Card", symbol.typeName];

    sqlite3_exec(db, [insertCommand UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    if(errmsg != NULL)
        NSLog(@"insert error: /%@", &errmsg);  //  DEBUGGING ONLY!

    //  now, pull it back out of the d/b and display the data
    const char *sqlStatement = @"select CARD_ID, CARD_NAME, CODE_VAL from CardData";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    int err = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);  // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
if(err != SQLITE_OK)
   NSLog(@"prepare error: /%@", err);
    else  { 
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            // Read the data from the result row
        resultText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nDatabase: \n%@ \n%@ \n%@", resultText.text, 
            [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)],
            [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)],
            [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)]];
        }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);  //  release it...
    sqlite3_close(db);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you provide an SQL statement that you are trying to execute?

Comment: Here it is...

http://monobin.com/__d215dc84d

Comment: Dude.  Post the relevant text in your question.

Comment: The prepare statement is giving me an error code of 21...



`const char *sqlStatement = @"select CARD_ID, CARD_NAME, CODE_VAL from CardData";
 sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
 int err = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL); // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access`

Comment: There is a FROM clause (right before "CardData")...

Comment: Shouldn't `const char *sqlStatement` be `NSString *sqlStatement`?

Comment: I changed it, but I'm still getting the SQLError 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use FMDB... thanks everybody for the suggestions, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html), (1.4 Error Codes->SQLITE_MISUSE) it says that you can get this error if you try to access closed database or calling sqlite_exec with same database pointer from two different threads. Just check out for these 2 possibilities in your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this applies to me, but thanks for the info anyway.  I'm thinking of going to CoreData or FMDB... this is getting too time-consuming!